# Bit circular shift

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit

I am currently learning on bit-wise operations, and i am tasked to do a left rotate of 4-bit integer.

My code for a 4bit left rotate is

```
private static int BITS_IN_INTEGER = 4;

private static int leftRotate(int x, int n) {
  return (x << n) | (x >> (BITS_IN_INTEGER - n));
}
```

I want to make a 4-bit circular shift to maintain as a 4-bit after rotating but can't seem to understand how it works.

Example: 10 (1010) after left rotate by 1 bit will give me 5 (0101) but it gives me a value of 21 which is more than my 4-bit.

Any help to make me understand this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: Rotating 1010 left by 1 gives 10100. Rotating it right by 1 would give 101.

Comment: couldn't there be a way to make it maintain 4 bit after left rotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to

- emulate integers with `BITS_IN_INTEGER` many bits instead of 32 bits.
- do a rotation on such an emulated integer

Currently you can do a rotation, but the upper bits of the actual int which are not part of the emulated int can end up in something other than 0. Example:

```
intput x
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 1100
                                     |____|___, emulated int
result of rotating left by n=2       |    |
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0011 0011
```

As we can see, all we have to do is setting the bits above the emulated int (that is the 32 - `BITS_IN_INTEGER` upper bits) to zero. To this end, we use a logical *"and"* (`&`). We need a mask that has `0` on the bits we want to set to zero (anything `& 0` is always 0) and a `1` on the bits we want to keep (anything `& 1` is always anything).

```
  0...0  0011 0011  ←  the result from before
& 0...0  0000 1111  ←  a mask
——————————————————
  0...0  0000 0011  ←  the masked result where unused bits are 0
```

To generate a mask of the form `0...01...1` with `BITS_IN_INTEGER` many `1`s we can use `(1 << BITS_IN_INTEGER) - 1`. The `- 1` converts `10000` into `01111`.

```
static int BITS_IN_INTEGER = 4;
static int INTEGER_MASK = (1 << BITS_IN_INTEGER) - 1;

static int leftRotate(int x, int n) {
  return INTEGER_MASK & ((x << n) | (x >>> (BITS_IN_INTEGER - n)));
}
```

Comment: however right rotate won't be as simple as swapping << to >> am i right?

Comment: If the whole result was masked with `INTEGER_MASK` (as it is now after the latest edit) then you could swap the shift operators (in the original I only masked the left shift since the right shift cannot modify the unused bits). However, I like to think about it differently: Swap `n` and `(BITS_IN_INTEGER - n)` rather than swapping the operators – this also works if only the former left shift was masked. Alternatively, implement the right shift as `leftRotate(x, BITS_IN_INTEGER - n)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) implementation of **leftRotate()** and **rightRotate()**, based on the above [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888205/1245872) from [Socowi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6770384/socowi) (thank you!)

I needed **to emulate a simple compass with 90º degree rotations** in both **left (counter-clockwise)** and **right (clockwise)** directions (not a real compass, just a funny problem).

So instead of messing up the code by storing the previous orientation and using * if / else * or * switch *, I came up with the idea that a [circular-shift](/questions/tagged/circular-shift) or [bit-rotation](/questions/tagged/bit-rotation) would be much more clean, efficient, and elegant of course.

However, I had the same problem about **limiting the mask to 4 bits**. Thanks to the above solution I was able to do it! ;)

So assuming the following:

```
 - North = 1 = 0001
 - West  = 2 = 0010
 - South = 4 = 0100
 - East  = 8 = 1000
```

When I need to **turn 90º from North to -> West** I call **leftRotate()** and so on until I get to the same point again (North).

The same applies in reverse, if **turning 90º from North to -> East** I call **rightRotate()**, and then again to turn South, and so on.

Here is the snippet, hope it helps:

```js
const BITS_IN_INTEGER = 4;
const INTEGER_MASK = (1 << BITS_IN_INTEGER) - 1;

// this function rotates to left (counter clockwise) 1,2,4,8...1,2,4,8

function leftRotate(x, n) {
  return INTEGER_MASK & ((x << n) | (x >>> (BITS_IN_INTEGER - n)));
}


// this function rotates to right (clockwise)  1,8,4,2...1,8,4,2

function rightRotate(x, n) {
  return INTEGER_MASK & ((x << (BITS_IN_INTEGER - n)) | (x >>> n));
}

// Lets rotate:

console.log('--- Rotate to left (counter clockwise) 1,2,4,8...1,2,4,8...1:')

let value = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  console.log(value);
  value = leftRotate(value, 1);
}

console.log('-- Rotate to right (counter clockwise) 1,8,4,2...1,8,4,2...1:')

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  console.log(value);
  value = rightRotate(value, 1);
}
```